# Tool for creating one pager

Tags: software-recommendation, page-layout, tools

I wonder if there is a specific tool for creating one pager cv's like the one bellow, besides photoshop or other high professional skill tools.

[image]

http://images-cdn.9gag.com/photo/a09NWOZ_700b_v1.jpg

Comment: Theoretically you could make this with Microsoft Office software, but the "high professional skill tools" are typically the tool of choice because they generally make things easier for you. In any case, what have you tried?

Comment: You can use any software. But note that these aren't usually what many would call 'well designed' resumes. They may be trendy, but not easy to pull off successfully.

Comment: Even if you can pull off a well-designed resume, you probably shouldn't. Google around for things like "HR fancy resume sins problem" and look for HR people telling you what not to do. It is a hard fact that many HR departments are snowed under with resumes and sometimes they cull the herd based on somewhat irrational or rapid processes. "Standing out" may be another way of saying "easy target." That particular resume you linked? A hot mess that demands cognitive effort to decipher. It goes into the round file..

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Johannes- what you are looking to do can be accomplished with Microsoft Word or any other document editor that can layout text and images like [OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org/). The amount of skill to create a page like your example would be about the same in any software.

Also, Photoshop would not be the software to use anyhow. Photoshop is an image editor or a digital layout tool. If you plan on printing it, you would use InDesign or any other document editor.

Comment: Even notepad! Though its not for non-experts!